# how to fix path manipulation and null deference issues for the following sample

Tags: java

I am getting the following issues after scanning the code using fortify....

1>path manipulation issue:

```
private MimeMessage prepareMessage(EmailMessage req) throws EmailProviderException {
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis(),finish=0;
    try {
        MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();

        // Create a multipart message
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

        // Set email addresses
        helper.setFrom(convertAddress(req.getFromAddress()));
        helper.setTo(convertAddress(req.getToAddress()));
        helper.setCc(convertAddress(req.getCcAddress()));
        helper.setBcc(convertAddress(req.getBccAddress()));

        // Set subject and body
        helper.setSubject(req.getEmailSubject());
        String emailBody = req.getEmailBody();
        String emailMime = req.getEmailMimeType();

        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource bodyDataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(emailBody, emailMime);
        messagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bodyDataSource));
        helper.getMimeMultipart().addBodyPart(messagePart);

        // Add attachments
        List<EmailAttachment> lAttach = req.getEmailAttachment();
        if (lAttach != null) {
            for (EmailAttachment attachMnt: lAttach) {
                DataSource dSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachMnt
                        .getContent(), attachMnt
                        .getMimeType());
                helper.addAttachment(attachMnt.getFileName(), dSource);
            }
        }

        finish=System.currentTimeMillis();
        statsLogger.info(new FedExLogEntry("prepareMessage took {0}ms",new Object[]{finish-start}));    

        return message;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        // Covers MessagingException, IllegalStateException, IOException, MailException
        String emsg = new StringBuilder("Unable to prepare smtp message.")
            .append("\n").append(req.toString()).toString();
        logger.warn(emsg, e);
        throw new EmailProviderException(emsg, e);
    }   
}
```

Null dereference issues

issue 1.

```
public byte[] toByteArray(Notification nd) throws EmailProviderException {

    String message = null;

    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(nd.getClass());
        if (jc != null) {
            Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            m.marshal(nd, sw);
            message = sw.toString();
        }

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new EmailProviderException("Unable to convert NDS notification to byte array.", e);
    }

    return message.getBytes();
}
```

null dereference issue 2..

```
private void addLastUpdatedHours(
    List<LocationHoursForADate> masterHours, List<LocationHoursWithSearchedDate> hoursToAdd, Map<String,String> scheduleTypeIncludesMap){
    String prevScheduleTypeCode = null;
    String prevHourTypeCode = null;
    Date searchedDate = null;

    // Build map of locationHours to searchDates
    List<LocationHours> locationHours = null;
    Map<Date, List<LocationHours>> locationHoursSearchDatesMap = new HashMap<Date, List<LocationHours>>();
    for(LocationHoursWithSearchedDate locationHoursWithSearchedDate : hoursToAdd) {
        if(scheduleTypeIncludesMap.containsKey(locationHoursWithSearchedDate.getLocationHoursPK().getScheduleTypeCd())) {
            searchedDate = locationHoursWithSearchedDate.getLocationHoursPK().getSearchedDate();
            locationHours = locationHoursSearchDatesMap.get(searchedDate);
            if(locationHours==null) {
                locationHours = new ArrayList<LocationHours>();
                locationHoursSearchDatesMap.put(searchedDate,locationHours);
            }
            locationHours.add(locationHoursWithSearchedDate.createLocationHours());
        }
    }        

    for(Map.Entry<Date,List<LocationHours>> entry : locationHoursSearchDatesMap.entrySet()) {
        prevHourTypeCode = null;
        prevScheduleTypeCode = null;
        searchedDate = entry.getKey();
        for(LocationHours hour: entry.getValue()){
            // new ST & new 01, add it
            if((prevScheduleTypeCode == null) && (prevHourTypeCode == null)){
                masterHours.add(new LocationHoursForADate(searchedDate, hour));
                prevScheduleTypeCode = hour.getLocationHoursPK().getScheduleTypeCd();
                prevHourTypeCode = hour.getLocationHoursPK().getHoursTypeCd();
            }
            else{
                //same ST
                if(prevScheduleTypeCode.equals(hour.getLocationHoursPK().getScheduleTypeCd())){
                    // same 01, skip this schedule
                    if(prevHourTypeCode.equals(hour.getHoursType().getHoursTypeCd())){
                        continue;
                    }
                    else { //new 01, add it
                        masterHours.add(new LocationHoursForADate(searchedDate, hour));
                        prevScheduleTypeCode = hour.getLocationHoursPK().getScheduleTypeCd();
                        prevHourTypeCode = hour.getLocationHoursPK().getHoursTypeCd();                      
                    }
                }
                else{ //new ST, add it
                    masterHours.add(new LocationHoursForADate(searchedDate, hour));
                    prevScheduleTypeCode = hour.getLocationHoursPK().getScheduleTypeCd();
                    prevHourTypeCode = hour.getLocationHoursPK().getHoursTypeCd();                                          
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No one is going to read the entire code , be crisp and highlight where is the issue..

Comment: At least, point the exact line in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the second case (null deference 1) is easy to spot.

The problem is that if there is an exception in the try-catch block then the object `message` will be null, so the final instruction return `message.getBytes()` will raise a `NullPointerException`.

One way to avoid it is changing the return statement like this:

```
return message != null ? message.getBytes() : null;
```

But maybe, you will prefer to raise the exception...